# where T : IEnumerable<T> method constraint

Tags: c#, generics, collections, constraints

From time to time I'm trying to torment the C# compiler. Today I came up with this:

```
static void CallFirst<T>(T a) where T : IEnumerable<T>
{
    a.First().ToString();
}
```

It was simple mistake, as I wanted to create the generic method that takes collection as parameter, which of course should look like this:

```
static void CallFirst2<T>(IEnumerable<T> a)
{
    a.First().ToString();
}
```

Anyway, is it even possible to call the `CallFirst()` method? Every time the collection is passed, the collection of collections is expected.

If it is not, shouldn't it be taken as compile time error?

Comment: The compiler cannot know that. While `T: IEnumerable<T>` might not make sense, `T : IComparable<T>` makes a lot of sense, and it's actually usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
class Test : IEnumerable<Test>
{
    IEnumerator<Test> IEnumerable<Test>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

    ...

var test = new Test();
CallFirst(test);
```

Comment: Nice, it's easy to overlook the most obvious solution :)

Answer (score 0):

While it makes little sense for `IEnumerable<T>`, [that pattern is widely used in fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (a quick example - `IComparable<T>`), so it would be counterproductive to make the compiler throw an error.